# Change markup of content search webpart

Tags: web-part, content-query-web-part

I've inserted an content search webpart but the items are being displayed very ugly:

[image]

I know there is a dropdown list where you can select the styling. But this just isn't working for me:

[image]

**What I want is a clean simple list with only the item names. Like a normal list/document library.**

Thank you.

Comment: There one display template, `item two lines ` - in my best dutch , i think it would be `Twee regels`, did you try that ?

Comment: I don't see item two lines. Only 3 lines, as you can see in the attached image...